# wordpress post thumbnail not working in widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query/loop to display thumbnails that work's for as a shortcode. I'm trying to use the same query/loop in a widget, everything is working apart from the thumbnails.

```
$img_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'user_images'));
     if($img_query->have_posts()){
         $out = "<ul class='user_images'>";
          while ($img_query->have_posts()){ 

          $img_query->the_post(); 
          $img_id = get_the_ID();
          $img_event = get_post_meta($img_id,'_event_link',true);
          $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');


    $out .= "<li>
                <a href='".get_permalink($img_event)."'><img src='".$image_url[0]."' /></a>
                <div class='imageCaption'>
                    <p>".get_the_title()." @ ".get_the_title($img_event)."</p>
                </div>
            </li>";



            } 
    $out .= "</ul>";    
     }else{
         $out .= "No Images";
     }

    echo $out;
```

I've tried a few different ways to get the thumbnail all of witch have failed to to output anything.

The output i'm getting looks like this.

```
<ul class="user_images">
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost"><img src=""></a>
                <div class="imageCaption">
                    <p>title @ title</p>
                </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE: this is only not working on the home page on single pages this works fine.

Comment: I think your issue is related to being outside The Loop.  Try accessing the Post ID directly.  $img_query->post->ID  Try this :    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($img_query->post->ID), 'thumbnail');

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this did not work. This is it's own loop, $img_query->the_post(); sets up the post data, this is why get_the_title(); works. The problem seems to just be with the thumbnail. Like I said this code works as shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $pageDetails = get_post( $post );
    $img_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'user_images'));
     if($img_query->have_posts()){ 
?>
     <ul class='user_images'>
     <?php
      while ($img_query->have_posts()){ 
          $img_query->the_post(); 
          $img_id = $pageDetails->ID;// get_the_ID();
          $img_event = get_post_meta($img_id,'_event_link',true);
          //$image_url = if ( has_post_thumbnail()){the_post_thumbnail();}//wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail'); 
      ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail(); }
                ?>
            </a>
            <div class='imageCaption'>
                <p><?php get_the_title(); ?> @ <?php get_the_title($img_id); ?></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php  } ?>
</ul>
<?php
 }else{
     echo "No Images";
 }
//echo $out;
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the first line to me...I don't think you've got the right idea, this is widget showing post thumbnails, it's outside the loop so there is no $post variable. also the titles are working and don't need changing. $img_event is another posts ID stored as metadata to the post i'm trying to get the image from.

Comment: I thought your problem is, that you code is conflicted between your posts, so you have to make $post global first.
thats what i have did.

Comment: That can not be the problem as I am able to get the title and metadata for the right post. I have 3 user_image posts with this script I get 3 <li> elements with the corresponding titles and linked event titles, the only thing that is not outputting is the image.

Comment: Thanks, I found in the end it was a conflict with another plugin editing the query for the home page affected this query!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually pass the `$post_id` to the `get_post_thumbnail_id()` function. As you can see at [WordPress' Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id), if no post ID is given, this function tries to fetch the ID from the current post. Even though I cannot tell you *what* exactly is the problem, I guess this is *where* the problem is.

So try to replace

```
$img_id = get_the_ID();
// ...
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
```

for

```
$img_id = $img_query->get_the_ID();
// ...
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($img_id), 'thumbnail');
```

I believe this trick should do it. Please give it a try and let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: Sorry, no luck with this one. It actually made the script die after the plugin title! No Idea whats going on...

Comment: Try to turn on [WP Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to see what errors WP are throwing. It might even help you to solve your original problem.